# cast interface to objc protocol in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, protocols

I have swift code that imports objc headers. There is an objc protocol defined in a header file as

```
@protocol MyProtocol
- (void) foo();
@end
```

An objc method returns an object that is of interface type Proxy.

```
@interface Proxy
+ (Proxy*) create:(Protocol*)arg;
@end
```

The object returned by `create` implements the protocol `arg`. I can confirm this works when I use the API in objc code as I can send methods defined in `MyProtocol` to the returned object. Such as

```
[[Proxy create:protocol(MyProtocol)] foo];
```

In swift, however, I get a cast exception when I try to convert the `create` result into a `MyProtocol` object.

```
var obj = Proxy.create(MyProtocol.self)
var my = obj as! MyProtocol

// error is Could not cast value of type 'Proxy' to 'MyProtocol'
```

I can even see that `obj` has the protocol type `MyProtocol` by using this code.

```
extension Protocol {
    var myName: String {
        return NSStringFromProtocol(self)
    }
}
print(obj.myName)
// prints Optional("MyProtocol")
```

I also tried a workaround where first `obj` is casted to `AnyObject` but that did not help.

```
`obj as AnyObject as! MyProtocol`
```

Comment: If I call `obj!.conforms(to: MyProtocol.self)` it prints `false`, so that seems like a good explanation of why the cast fails. I'm not sure why its false, though, since I am able to call methods of MyProtocol on `obj`. Maybe those methods are available to call but `obj` doesn't technically implement the MyProtocol protocol?

Comment: It seems this does work. `var m = obj as AnyObject; m.foo()`. At least the Proxy object behaves the same way as when its used in the objc code.